# How to save image in indexed format and get it's palette ?

Tags: c#, image-processing

I want to save image as Format8bppIndexed using this code :

```
Bitmap imgsource = new Bitmap(sourceimage);
Bitmap imgtarget = new Bitmap(imgsource.Width, imgsource.Height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
                for (int I = 0; I <= imgsource.Width - 1; I++)
                {
                    for (int J = 0; J <= imgsource.Height - 1; J++)
                    {
                        imgtarget.SetPixel(I, J, imgsource.GetPixel(I, J));
                    }
                }
imgtarget.Save(targetimage);
```

but I face error that "Setpixel is not supported for images with indexed pixel formats"

and I want to save image with indexed 
how I can do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
Bitmap imgtarget = imgsource.Clone(
    new Rectangle(0, 0, imgsource.Width, imgsource.Height),
    PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
```

EDIT:

There are two kind of [`Image`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) in GDI+: 
[`Bitmap`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) and [`Metafile`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.metafile.aspx). Usually you load the image from a bitmap image file (`.jpg`, `.png`, `.bmp`, `.gif`, `.exif` and `.tiff`) and not a metafile (`.wmf` or `.emf`). So, instead of creating a new bitmap based on the image, just cast the `Image` object to `Bitmap`:

```
Bitmap imgsource = (Bitmap)sourceimage;
```

The first line of your code, changes the origianl properties of the image and resets the DIP to 96.

Comment: it's working now but the output image is 96 dpi and 8 bit depth
and the input is 300 dpi and 32 bit depth

Comment: @MohamedKamal See my edit. First line of your code, changes the DIP to 96. And you wanted a 8 bit depth image, right?

Comment: I can change the dpi using "SetResolution" class ... and want to change the bit depth to 32

Comment: What about `PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed`? **8bpp** means 8 bits per pixel. It is the bit depth of the image: `8`.