# C# check images are equal with tolerance

Tags: c#

I have this code where I send images from a thermal camera. `getImage()` returns the actual image that is provided by the camera. There is no possibility to check directly if the camera can provide a 'new' image, so I did this method to compare two images:

```
class ImageCompare
    {
        public enum CompareResult
        {
            CompareOK,
            SizeMismatch,
            PixelMismatch
        };

        public static CompareResult CompareImages(Image i1, Image i2)
        {
            CompareResult cr = CompareResult.CompareOK;

            if (i1.Size != i2.Size)
            {
                cr = CompareResult.SizeMismatch;
            }
            else
            {
                ImageConverter ic = new ImageConverter();
                byte[] btImage1 = new byte[1];
                btImage1 = (byte[])ic.ConvertTo(i1, btImage1.GetType());
                byte[] btImage2 = new byte[1];
                btImage2 = (byte[])ic.ConvertTo(i2, btImage2.GetType());

                //compute hashes
                SHA256Managed shaM = new SHA256Managed();
                byte[] hash1 = shaM.ComputeHash(btImage1);
                byte[] hash2 = shaM.ComputeHash(btImage2);

                for (int i = 0; i < hash1.Length && i < hash2.Length
                                  && cr == CompareResult.CompareOK; i++)
                {
                    if (hash1[i] != hash2[i])
                        cr = CompareResult.PixelMismatch;
                }
            }
            return cr;
        }
    }
```

and here is how I use this class:

```
private static void HandleImageSending(Socket client, Socket s)
        {
            int sent;
            int imageCount = 0;
            long totalSize = 0;
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Starting sending...");
                    Image old = getImage();
                    byte[] bmpBytes;
                    using (Image bmp = getImage())
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        if (ImageCompare.CompareImages(bmp, old) == ImageCompare.CompareResult.CompareOK)
                        {
                            bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                            bmpBytes = ms.ToArray();
                            sent = SendVarData(client, bmpBytes);
                            imageCount++;
                            totalSize += sent;
                            old = bmp;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { ... }
```

So my problem is that comparing by hash results in 'different' images in about 19 of 20 cases. Since the camera provides only 8 fps, there must be something wrong.

Is there a possibility of comparing with a kind of tolerance, so let's say 5 or 10 percent of the compared new image may differ to the old?

Since this is used on a mini PC, I would like to use the smallest CPU load possible. What can I try next?

Comment: Even if you have just one single bit difference between the two images the hash codes calculated are most likely to be completely different. Pretty much the only way of comparing the images and allowing for some degree of tolerance will be byte by byte. As TaW has suggested, depending on how critical you matching is - scaling to reduce  size would help speed wise - though scaling to 1/4 means you have lost 75% of image information.

Comment: For speed use LockBits ! Also: Scaling down the images to 1/4 size or less would be 4* faster. The tolerance can be calulated very fast by scaling down the channel values by, say, shifting the bytes to the right by 1 or 2 bits. Or you compare the differences.. - None of this will help if the images are skewed or shifted, though. You may want to study [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224095/how-to-find-the-difference-between-two-images/26225153#26225153) which creates a difference image for the purpose of a faster transmission..

Answer (score 2):

indexing the image (and decreasing the size) should give the same result for similar images

using

```
Bitmap imgtarget = imgsource.Clone(
    new Rectangle(0, 0, imgsource.Width, imgsource.Height),
    PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
```

from [another stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049562/how-to-save-image-in-indexed-format-and-get-its-palette)